# How to connect debug sessions to a particular RDP user, irrespective of login order

Tags: azure, rdp

Context: Azure, Visual Studio

Let's assume that user VM-CLOUD-W99/Bruce logged in to the Azure server at 27/02/2017 11:01:14 AM and VM-CLOUD-W99/Steve logged in 27/02/2017 11:52:26 AM. Now assume that a CSScript engine runs from the Scheduler and encounters a "debugger;" statement in a JScript script. Onto a console the debugging dialog appears.

It seems to be the case that the most recently logged-in user will see the dialog and be able to start a debugging session. Said user will not be able to hand the debugging session to another user, even if that user is also logged in.

So is there any way of telling the system that only VM-CLOUD-W99/Bruce should see debug dialogs? Right now it's a toss up who gets to see and respond to them, and telling Steve to disconnect and reconnect (so as to change the login order) doesn't help with the current debug session.

Comment: You had better ask the question on [Statck Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure).

Comment: Yeah well I could, but it'd probably get flagged as not being on topic. I'm not asking for a programming solution, but a server solution.